# How can I use variables in VS Code settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code settings, there are some fields which I configure the same.  These would be namely font and font size.  Generally I have them all set to the same.  I am trying to set up a variable in the settings.json which can be applied to all of them. After reading through [Variables Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) for VS Code, I came up with the following:

```
{
  "common": [
    {
      "font": "Anonymous Pro",
      "fontSize": 10,
    }
  ],

  // Set up the Editor
  "editor.fontFamily":              "${common:font}",
  "editor.fontSize":                "${common:fontSize}",
  "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "${common:font}",
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize":   "${common:fontSize}",
  "debug.console.fontFamily":       "${common:font}",
  "debug.console.fontSize":         "${common:fontSize}",
}
```

Though, this doesn't seem to work.  Is there a way to setup variables within the settings.json without having to setup environment variables?

Answer (score 10):

Currently you cannot set variables in the `settings.json` file.

The current open issue for VS Code to implement this feature is here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2809

It has yet to have a PR and the opening of the issue occurred Feb 2016, but with comments within the last 2 months.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The link you provided states:

> Variable substitution is supported inside key and value strings in launch.json and tasks.json ...

So there is no support for `settings.json`.

Comment: Not sure if this has changed, but it now says "The predefined variables are supported in a select number of setting keys in settings.json files such as the terminal cwd, env, shell and shellArgs values."

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_is-variable-substitution-supported-in-user-and-workspace-settings

Comment: @user1034533 Thanks for pointing this out! Unfortunately the documentation is quite vague. I will try to test this.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the same docs which were linked in the question post (asker just needed to scroll down) https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_is-variable-substitution-supported-in-user-and-workspace-settings :

> ###### Is variable substitution supported in User and Workspace settings?
>
> The predefined variables are supported in a select number of setting keys in `settings.json` files such as the terminal `cwd`, `env`, `shell` and `shellArgs` values. Some [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) like `window.title` have their own variables:
>
> ```
> "window.title": "${dirty}${activeEditorShort}${separator}${rootName}${separator}${appName}"
> ```
>
> Refer to the comments in the Settings editor (`Ctrl+,`) to learn about setting specific variables.

Even quoting from the very first sentence in that entire document:

> Visual Studio Code supports variable substitution in [Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) and [Task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) configuration files as well as some select settings. Variable substitution is supported inside some key and value strings in `launch.json` and `tasks.json` files using `${variableName}` syntax.

If you want to be able to use variables freely in settings.json, then see [Support variables when resolving values in settings #2809](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2809), give it a thumbs up to show support for it, and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making comments there like "+1" / "bump" / "still not implemented??!!1?!?1".

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? You can set project specific settings in VSCode. So much you can have a different set of fonts and settings based on the project. But I don't think the `settings.json` supports variables.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the mentioned issue "[Support variables when resolving values in settings](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2809)" (`microsoft/vscode` issue 2809), you now have ([from Bohdan Shulha](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2809#issuecomment-1620628895)):

[wss: Workspace Shared Settings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=b-shulha.wss) (repository: [`bohdan-shulha/vs-wss`](https://github.com/bohdan-shulha/vs-wss))

> - Have you ever need to use ${workspaceFolder} in your settings.json?
> - Were you struggling to share settings with your team?
> - Do you have multiple devices running different OSes and you need the same settings everywhere?
>
> This extension is an answer to all these questions.

It is still in development, but looks promising!

Answer (score -1):

For anyone coming to this question in 2023, VS Code has updated a way to provide this using the c_cpp_properties.json configuration.

Here is an example of variable definition:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "customConfigurationVariables": {
            "appInstallPath": "/my/app/bin/",
            "debugRemoteHost": "192.168.1.1",
            "debugRemotePort": "2159"
        }
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

And then you would reference these variables in either launch.json or tasks.json using

> ${input:**variable-id**}

where the **variable-id** is defined in the input section as shown below. The "args" key must match your variable defined in customConfigurationVariables:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"inputs": [
    {
        "id": "installPath",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "cpptools.activeConfigCustomVariable",
        "args": "appInstallPath"
    },
    {
        "id": "host",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "cpptools.activeConfigCustomVariable",
        "args": "debugRemoteHost"
    },
    {
        "id": "port",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "cpptools.activeConfigCustomVariable",
        "args": "debugRemotePort"
    }
],
"configurations": [
    {
        // Enables single-click remote debugging on this device from the project install location
        "name": "Local Debug",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
        "cwd": "${input:installPath}",
        "environment": [],
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "externalConsole": false,
        "logging": {
            "engineLogging": false,
            "trace": false,
            "traceResponse": false
        }
    }
]
}
```