# Using portable git with VSCode portable

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, portable-applications

Well I would have a development setup related question but not code related. I am currently trying to set up my/one development enviroment. I choose PORTABLE VSCode. I figured out how to install extensions by adding a data directory and I am learning the ropes to handle VSCode. I now wanted to integrate GIT and to be more precise PORTABLE Git. I would like to have my development enviroment on a USB drive or on a network drive to be able to use it on different machines. I am working on WINDOWS 10 machines. Currently I am totally stuck in setting up portable git with VScode. I found some informations by googling but they seem older or not working.  I do not want to set PATH variables because using a thumb drive might change the drive letters anyway and I do not want to change the enviroments of the machines I will work on. The tips I found are mostly older and entile setting "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" which seems deprecated.  The culprit seems to be git.path. I copied my portable git files in a folder named git directly under the main folder of VSCode. If I set up a full path with drive letter for example "E:\Portable_VSCode1.82.0\git\bin\git.exe" I manage to get it running. Also ".\git\bin\git.exe" allows me to select the option to set up a Repository (but then fails with an error: spawn ./git/bin/git.exe ENOENT). So my conclusion is that git.exe was found during initialization but not when calling it). I tried to change the path to  {%CD:~0,2%}\Portable_VSCode1.82.0\git\bin\git.exe" but that is not working either. I also tried other stuff like {env:CD} but was not successfull and I am currently stuck. Has anyone else solved this problem (actually it seems to have worked on older versions). I am using VSCode 1.8.2.0 and the current portble version of git download.

My current VScode setting.json  looks like this

```json
 {
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern",
    "git.ignoreMissingGitWarning": true,
    "git.enabled": true,
    "git.path": ".\\git\\bin\\git.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": true,
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
      "PowerShell": { "source": "PowerShell", "icon": "terminal-powershell" },
      "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [
          "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
          "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
      },
      "GitBash": {
        "path": ["E:\\Portable_VSCode1.82.0\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"],
        "icon": "terminal-bash"
      },
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "GitBash",
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
    "editor.showFoldingControls": "always",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
    "security.allowedUNCHosts": [
        "esprimoq956"
    ],
    "workbench.settings.applyToAllProfiles": [

    ]
}
```

Comment: out of curiosity, what if you just put the git executable in the same directory as the Code.exe file in the portable directory as a "sibling"?

Comment: That is/was a good idea. I copied git.exe and bash.exe into the Code.exe directory. But the Problem remained the same. In a second attempt I also changed the git.path to "git.path": "${execPath}" but this time it did not even offer me the possibility to initialiaze a repository. Instead it prompted me to install git. So I am concluding that it died not find git.exe and ${execPath} does not work (which it should?).

Comment: "_${execPath} does not work (which it should?)._" see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77077602/11107541